# Simple Python UDF issue for Hadoop pig

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I write a very simple Python and here is my UDF code, pig code and error message, any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

UDF (test.py),

```
@outputSchema("cookie:chararray")
def getSimple():
    return 'Hello'
```

Pig code,

```
register test.py using jython as TestSimple;
a = TestSimple.getSimple() as word;
```

Error message,

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'a'
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: that is invalid `Pig` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to LOAD some data than process it with your UDF.
Like:
Load data:

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('\t','-schema');
```

Process your data with UDF, let's say you have an id field in your input:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TestSimple.getSimple(id) as word;
```

And of course you need to register your UDF as you did it correctly.